# How to group similar hue with a given threshold? Smarties counter projet

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to group similar hues together using a given threshold. It works quite well except for red values. Since near 0 or 180 represent red in OpenCV, I'm having trouble to group let say 3 degree and 179 degree hues in the same group.

The hues are stored in a Vector.

I have created a function with the following signature.

```
Vector <uchar> getGroupedHues(Vector<uchar> hues, int threshold);
```

The final goal is to create a smarties counter. I have isolated the individual smarties and now I want to find the hue of each one to classified them.

I based my code using the [page](http://swarminglogic.com/article/2013_11_skittles). The algorithm to cluster the hues is at the end, but like I said, I'm struggling with near 0/180 degrees values.

Thanks for helping!

**UPDATE**
This is the code I have made.

```
// Creates a cluster of hues that are within a threshold
Vector<uchar> getClusteredHues(Vector<uchar> values, int threshold) {

    int nbBin = 180;
    Vector <uchar> groups(nbBin, 0);

    // Sorting the hues
    sort(values.begin(), values.end());

    Point2f previous = getPointFromAngle(values[0]);
    Point2f currentCluster = previous;

    Point2f currentValue;
    Point2f delta;

    Point2f thresholdXY = getPointFromAngle(threshold);

    groups[values[0]]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
        currentValue = getPointFromAngle( values[i]);

        delta = currentValue - previous;

        if (delta.x < thresholdXY.x && delta.y < thresholdXY.y) {
            groups[(int)(atan2(currentCluster.y, currentCluster.x)* 180 / CV_PI)]++;
        }
        else  {
            currentCluster = currentValue;
            groups[(int)(atan2(currentCluster.y, currentCluster.x)* 180 / CV_PI)]++;
        }

        previous = currentValue;

    }

    return groups;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the [Mean of circular quantities Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities) the post links to? I think that will contain your answer.

Comment: @SSteve, yes I have check and implemented it, but it still does not work since I am not looking for the mean. I have included the function's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a workaround. I always check if the current value is near the end limit, if so, I the current group becomes the first group.

Here's is the code.

```
Vector<uchar> getClusteredHues(Vector<uchar> values, int threshold) {

    int nbBin = 180;
    Vector <uchar> clusters(nbBin, 0);

    // trier les teintes
    sort(values.begin(), values.end());

    int previous = values[0];
    int currentCluster = previous;

    int currentValue;
    int delta;
    int halfThreshold = threshold / 2;
    int firstCluster = values[0];

    clusters[values[0]]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < values.size(); i++) {
        currentValue = values[i];

        delta = currentValue - previous;

        if (currentValue + threshold > nbBin) {
            if (abs(firstCluster - (currentValue + threshold - nbBin)) < threshold) {
                delta = 0;
                currentCluster = firstCluster;
            }
        }

        if (delta < threshold) {
            clusters[currentCluster]++;
        }
        else  {
            currentCluster = currentValue;
            clusters[currentCluster]++;
        }

        previous = currentValue;

    }

    return clusters;
}
```